# Existe alguma forma de enviar um anexo junto com a mensagem pelo BOT do Telegram?

Tags: php, guzzle, telegram-bot

Estou usando a API do Telegram para enviar logs de erros das minhas aplicações.

Eu exibo algumas informações principais, mas também gostaria de exibir o `trace` da exceção. O problema é que o Telegram retorna um erro `400`, mostrando que o valor excede o tamanho máximo (que é 4096, se não me engano).

No caso, eu queria continuar exibindo as informações principais do log e adicionar esse trecho do `trace` da exceção (que é grande) num arquivo `txt`.

Seria possível, além de enviar a mensagem, anexar um arquivo de texto junto?

O código que tenho é o seguinte:

```
function telegram_log($chat_id, $text, $parse_mode = 'markdown')
{
    $cli = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_url' => TELEGRAM_URL_API,
    ]);


    $response = $cli->post('sendMessage', [
        'query' => compact('text', 'parse_mode', 'chat_id'),
        'timeout'         => 5,
        'connect_timeout' => 5,
    ]);



    return json_decode( (string) $response->getBody() );
}
```

Comment: [Nessa resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39556524/1284458) o cara usa o parâmetro `caption` do [`sendDocument`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument). Mas não sei se te ajuda pois tem 200 caracteres de limite e não sei como é a apresentação do caption nos Apps.

Comment: @fernandosavio boa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como indicado nos comentários pelo @fernandosavio e também na documentação do [Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument), é possível usar o método `sendDocument`.

Uns pontos devem ser observados:

- O campo `caption` pode ter de `0` a `1024` caracteres. Este deve ser enviado como Query String.
- O campo `document` deve estar no`multipart/form-data` da requisição. Para fotos, o máximo de tamanho permitido é `10MB`, e para arquivos, `50MB`.

O meu código com Guzzle ficou assim:

```
function telegram_send_document($token, $chat_id, $file, $caption = null)
{

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => sprintf('https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/', $token),
    ]);

    $client->post('sendDocument', [
        'query' => [
            'chat_id'    => $chat_id,
            'caption'    => $caption,
            'parse_mode' => 'markdown'
        ],

        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name'     => 'document',
                'contents' => fopen($file, 'r'),
                'filename' => basename($file)
            ]
        ]
    ]);

}
```

Para usar bastaria fazer isso:

```
telegram_send_document('TOKEN', 'CHAT_ID', 'log.txt', 'APP Lorem Ipsum');
```

No caso do `GuzzleHttp\Client` você pode passar uma `string` no parâmetro `contents` do `fopen`.